# What does 'back up with' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs, ellipses, attributive-nouns

The expression comes from the following [meme](https://gyazo.com/4918f9f787bbffce349ac9ff866d4112) of Stevie Wonder

[image: Stevie Wonder wearing his iconic eyewear while performing]

> How I feel while backing up with 5% window tint

I think it's some kind of insulting the blinds. I don't enjoy those things, but the expression quite bugs me so bad. Can you substitute the expression 'while backing up with'? I cannot figure out what it means

Comment: Please include the quote textually in your question, together with enough context to understand its intent.

Comment: don't get me wrong but is that some sort of rule? i'm sorry. I'll sure to do that next time

Comment: There are two reasons for the request. First, links go bad from time to time. If the question relies on the link to make it meaningful, then if the link goes bad, so does the question. The second reason is that this is a courtesy to whoever reads your question. It's nice to have all the pertinent information available up front, without having to click around to find it.

Comment: Looking at the question as it stands, there's no reason why "back up with" would be some kind of insult to "the blinds" (venetian blinds? [Sternbergh's book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32600769-the-blinds)?).

Comment: I didn't mean "to back up with" could be insult. I only said that because to use  blind people to make something fun is not cool imo.  thought it was triggering. and somehow you sound angry. sorry if I don't get the right nuance of your comments

Comment: Text isn't a particularly good medium to convey emotional cues. Please treat this as simply a neutral recommendation, rather than an angry one. I haven't looked at the link, so I'm not sure what the context is, but the question as it stands is unclear without further context. A simple copy/paste of a relevant paragraph or two can fix that. You can use the [edit] link to add information.

Comment: You need to add the text in the question. Copy and paste it into the question. We also expect this from people who post answers. How would you like it if someone posted "The answer is [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25710?locale=en_US)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a car reference.  "5% window tint" refers to car windows. The British equivalent of "backing up" in this context is "reversing". In this context, it seems self deprecating on the part of the author (rather than an insult to the subject of the image).

Adding references:
[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/turn-one-s-back-on?s=t) gives the following definition for "back up":

> to move backward:
>   Back up into the garage.

And [here](https://www.teamacme.com/tints/understanding-window-tint-percentages/) you can find out that:

> A 5% tint would be what we usually call limo tint

So the meme implies that the author of the text feels something like Stevie Wonder when driving their own car which has dark, tinted windows.

What isn't clear is what aspect of Stevie Wonder they feel like. Possible interpretations are:

- They feel like a superstar
- They feel blind
- They feel that although they're blind they can still perform the task amazingly well

Comment: @MAW it's customary to accept answers as a way of thanking someone, especially someone who went to the bother of looking at the link. Click the grey checkmark below the bottom arrow. It should turn green, and you'll get a bonus 2 rep too.

Comment: I upvoted but I don't think the author is saying they feel like a superstar, but rather s/he feels  as if s/he's lost in the dark, or as blind as Stevie Wonder because they can't see what's behind them.

Comment: I think it is relevant, although this answer misses it, that the subject of the meme is a superstar, who happens to be blind.  In that, he can make awesome music come from a piano, even though he can't see the keys.  And thus, the maker of the meme feels like a superstar because he can maneuver his car in reverse, even though he can hardly see what is behind him.  It doesn't work without *both* elements.

Comment: I feel much like @Mari-LouA. And I'm amazed at any other interpretation, such as Pam and cobaltduck have come up with. But that part of the answer is Primarily Opinion Based, which is off topic on ELU. So I've edited that part of this answer. And given it a +1 for the ELU aspects of this Q&A - namely that it's about reversing a car.

Comment: gee, people I accepted, calm down